# Convert Laplace's equation into polar coordinates

Tags: complex-analysis, polar-coordinates, harmonic-functions, change-of-variable

When I read Ahlfors's book, I came across this problem
the$$u(x,y)$$is a harmonic function
and satisfies Laplace's equation
$$\Delta u＝\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}＝0$$
He converted Laplace's equations into polar coordinates
$$r\frac{\partial(r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r})}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \theta}＝0$$But I don't know how he changed

Comment: Perhaps, this tutorial may help: https://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/dobrush/am34/Mathematica/ch6/polar.html

Comment: but is that $$u_rr＋\frac{1}{r}u_r+\frac{1}{r^2}u_\theta\theta$$equal to the above formula

Comment: To @tianhaowu: Sure! 
See: $\frac{\partial(r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r})}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial u }{\partial r}+r\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial r^2}=u_r+ru_{rr}$

Comment: Harmonic functions satisfy $\partial_{\overline{z}}=0$ so$$\partial_r=\frac{z}{r}\partial_z,\,\partial_\theta=iz\partial_z=ir\partial_r\implies r^2\partial_r^2+r\partial_r+\partial_\theta^2=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

The general formula for the Laplacian with a diagonal metrics in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with scale factors $h_k(x_1,\dots,x_n), k=1,\dots, n$ derives from metric invariant form of the local scalar square of the gradient

$$\nabla f . \nabla g = \sum_k (\frac{1}{h_k} \partial_k f) (\frac{1}{h_k} \partial_k g)$$
integrated over all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with volume measure $\prod_k h_k dx_k$

On the class of functions with zero boundary value integral over a large sphere one has by partial integration over all coordinates the definition of the Laplacian

$$\int \prod_m h_m dx_m \sum_k (\frac{1}{h_k} \partial_k f) (\frac{1}{h_k} \partial_k g) = -\int \prod_m h_m dx_m \ \  f \ \  \left(\sum_k (\frac{1}{h_k} \partial_k \left( (\frac{\prod_m h_m}{h_k} \partial_k g)\right)\right)=-\int \left(\prod_m h_m dx_m \right)\ \  f\  \ \Delta g $$

For polar coordinates in $\mathbb R^2$  with $h_r=1, \ h_\phi= r $ the resulting Laplacian is

$$\Delta = \frac{1}{r}\partial_r r \partial r + \frac{1}{r^2} \partial_{\phi,\phi}$$

For the Laplace equation one power of r can be discarded.

Answer (score -1):

[I think in calculus this formula is derived like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bccsz.png)

[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s53Xg.png)

[Third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RObbH.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).